# Периодически невозможно подключиться с внешки

Tags: ssh, sshfs

Для удаленного подключения к серверу использую `ssh user@host`, и раз на раз не приходится.

Иногда подключается нормально, иногда вылетает

> port 22: Connection timed out

Стандартный порт не менял.  Вообще ничего не менял, все настройки дефолтные.

Та же история с монтированием `sshfs`, через раз.

Даже чаше не подключается.

Где искать причину? Ладно бы вообще не мог подключиться, но иногда все нормально.

В локалке все как часы работает.

Comment: подсоединение к другим портам при этом происходит нормально?

Comment: В целом это нормально (более-менее). Проверяйте сеть, можно также на хосте, к которому подключаетесь поменять в конфиге sshd.conf время таймаута.

Comment: 80 апач, работает без сбоев. Таймут менять невижу пока смысла, либо сразу подключается либо висит до таймаута.

Answer (score 1):

если соединения с другими портами происходят нормально, значит сетевые сбои по пути пакетов и временную перенагруженность сервера можно исключить.

---

возможно, где-то по пути пакетов срабатывают фильтры, ограничивающие количество новых соединений в единицу времени на данный порт.

---

дальше исхожу из предположения, что на сервере установлен какой-либо из дистрибутивов операционной системы *gnu/linux*.

чтобы определить, происходит ли это на вашем сервере, или ещё до него, сто́ит убедиться, фиксируются ли в логах (`/var/log/auth.log`, `/var/log/audit/audit.log` и т.п.) попытки подключения в те моменты, когда вы получаете ошибку об истечении времени подключения.

также сто́ит проинспектировать правила *netfilter-а* на вашем сервере на предмет [ограничивающих правил](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/139285/110559):

```
$ sudo iptables-save | grep limit
```

---

**обновление про другой порт**:

ну и, конечно, имеет смысл попробовать подключаться к другому порту: добавьте на сервере в `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` строку `port номер_порта` (в добавок к уже существующей `port 22`) и подключайтесь, используя этот порт (*sshd* надо будет перезапустить):

```
$ ssh -p номер_порта пользователь@машина
```

`номер_порта` имеет смысл выбрать из диапазона «больше 1024» (максимальный номер — 2<sup>16</sup>=65536).

а чтобы не указывать порт каждый раз, добавьте в `~/.ssh/config` пару строк:

```
host машина
port номер_порта
```

Comment: На сервер `Ubuntu Server 14.04.3 LTS` как только смогу пробиться через таймаут обязательно проверю

Comment: Такая же проблема при вообще отключенном сетевом экране,  в `/var/log/auth.log` ничего не прописывается при неудачном подключении...`var/log/audit/audit.log` такого вообще нет

Comment: значит, скорее всего, блокировка происходит где-то между вами и сервером. попробуйте использовать другой порт (я дополнил ответ).